# Драйвера под Linux

Tags: linux

Где можно найти полный комплект драйверов под Linux для Asus K50c?

Comment: обычно никаких драйверов не надо дополнительных, всё есть в дистрибутиве.

Answer (score 1):

Полный комплект, если где и можно найти, то это на сайте производителя - [Asus](http://ru.asus.com/Notebooks/Versatile_Performance/K50C/#download). Если там нет нужного, то остается писать в [поддержку](http://support.asus.com/contactus.aspx?SLanguage=en).